# How to iterate through a json object

Tags: python, json

My question is in 2 parts .

I have a json file :

```
"result": [
             {
               "id": "12345678",
               "label": "Target Label",
               "hostName": "www.example.com",
               "location": "Seattle, WA",
               "locationid": "9",
               "targetType": "PING basic",
               "frequency": "5",
               "statusCode": "UP",
               "statusMessage": "OK",
               "fails": "0",
               "responseTime": "0.136",
               "dnsTime": "0.000",
               "connectTime": "0.136",
               "redirectTime": "0.000",
               "firstbyteTime": "0.000",
               "lastbyteTime": "0.000",
               "lastCheck": "15:43 12-05-2017",
               "lastDown": "21:34 11-17-2017",
               "pingLoss": "0.00",
               "pingMin": "136.357",
               "pingAvg": "136.597",
               "pingMax": "137.049"
             }
           ]
```

Question 1: Assuming the json files contain N number of "result".

How can I access the json results in a loop ?

I am doing this to access a from single result :

```
data = {}
data['PublisherMessage'] = data_dict['result'][0]['statusMessage']
```

How can I access the json results in a loop with multiple results?

Question 2:

How can I create dictionary in loop to assign it to json results which I will be fetching in loop?

Comment: You can use a for-loop like `for result in data_dict['result']`

Comment: btw What you have is not `json`. Did you mean: `{ "result": [ ... ] }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have `data_dict` whose only entry is `data_dict['result']` then this is a list which you can iterate over:

```
for item in data_dict['result']:
    # do something with item['statusMessage'] etc
```

Comment: what i am basically trying to do here is read a json file with multiple result object and map it to a format with multiple dict. I want this whole functionality in one loop 

Now i understood how i can read multiple result object .

Now my question is how can i create a dict inside a loop and map those multiple result object

Comment: data = {}
data['PublisherMessage'] = data_dict['result'][0]['statusMessage']
data['PublisherCriticality'] = criticality_code
data['PublisherStatus'] = data_dict['result'][0]['statusCode']
data['CorrelationID'] = None
data['IP'] = None
data['CIName'] = data_dict['result'][0]['hostName']
data['PublisherTimestamp'] = datetime.strptime(data_dict['result'][0]['lastDown'], '%H:%M %m-%d-%Y').isoformat()

with open("data_post.json", "w") as write_file:
    json.dump(data, write_file,indent=4)

This is what i am doing currently